# bajar las barras en ggplot

Tags: r

ggplot suele poner el valor 0 del eje y un poco "levantado", como si partiera del 1 (linea verde en el gráfico)

¿No se puede hacer que parta desde la linea roja?

Es decir, bajar las barras para que parezca que empieza en 0 y no en 1.

```
   data <- read.table(text = '
    
          col1                    col2
    Variable1                         100
    Variable2                         80
    Variable3                         45
    Variable4                         42
    Variable5                         20
    Variable6                         15
    ', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    



ggplot(data, aes(x=col1 , y=col2)) +ylim(0,130)+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill="#00bae6") + 
  geom_text(stat="identity", aes(x = col1 , label = col2), vjust = -1, size=3) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(title="titulo") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "titulos x") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = -1, angle = 90)) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el argumento `expand` de la función `scale_y_continuous`. En esa función también se puede especificar los límites del eje "y" mediante el argumento `limits`. Además, junté las llamadas que especifican las etiquetas (`labs()`) y los temas (`theme()`), de esa manera ayuda a la lectura del código.

```r
data <- read.table(text = '
          col1                    col2
    Variable1                         100
    Variable2                         80
    Variable3                         45
    Variable4                         42
    Variable5                         20
    Variable6                         15
    ', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = col1 , y = col2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#00bae6") +
  geom_text(
    stat = "identity",
    aes(x = col1 , label = col2),
    vjust = -1,
    size = 3
  ) +
  labs(title = "titulo",
       x = "titulos x") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = -1, angle = 90),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 130), expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]